# Cannot find 'System Type' in 'menuconfig'

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, nvidia

I ran menuconfig on my jetson AGX Xavier but I cannot find the System Type in it. I also have a Tegra K1 on which I can find the system type successfully.

What I want to do is to disable cache L1 (I-cache and D-cache), and it is supposed to be under the System Type in the menuconfig while I can't find it.

I also attached the pic of what I got.

[image]

And this is the 'System Type' that I got on my TK1 board.

[image]

But I cannot find it on Jetson AGX Xavier board.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow, this question might be better suited to https://serverfault.com/ since it's much more linux orientated rather than programming orientated.